# Cómo corregir este pseudocódigo en PseInt?

Tags: pseint

Necesito realizar un programa que introducida una frase guarde las palabras que están separadas por espacios en un archivo separado por comas.

Antes de migrarlo a Python más adelante, tengo que realizar el pseudocódigo y de momento tengo el código que muestro a continuación, pero me da error en la representación

Muchas gracias.

```
LEER car
fichero = car

PARA i = 0 HASTA i <= len(car) de i=i+1
SI car [i] = ! “ ” ENTONCES
fichero = fichero + car[i]
SINO
   Fichero = fichero + “,”
   i = i+1

FISI
FIPARA
Escribir “fichero”
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si eso es pseudocodigo, como puede dar error en algun lado?

Comment: ¿Error en la representación? Explicate mejor

Comment: ¿Un pseudocódigo te da error? ¿Cómo puede ser eso? ¿Es que has intentado correr directamente el pseudocódigo, o el que te ha dado error ha sido tu traducción a python del pseudocódigo? Si es lo segundo ¿puedes editar la pregunta para poner también el código python que hayas escrito?

Comment: He estado usando PSeInt para poder ver si la representación se realizaba de forma correcta y no me sale ningún tipo de resultado, por lo tanto creo que esta mal pero sin saber encontrar la solución al fallo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ah, que era un pseudocódigo ejecutable! No conocía PSeint, pero tras ver un poco la entrada en Wikipedia sobre el mismo, creo que tienes mal el bucle ya que después de `HASTA` debes poner el valor máximo de `i` que admites  (`len(car)` en tu caso, o tal vez `len(car)-1` dependiendo de cómo funcione el bucle `PARA`) en lugar de una condición como el `i<=len(car)` que tú tienes. Y las asignaciones creo que van con `<-` en vez de `=` (no sé si te admite también el `=` o está reservado para comparaciones)

Comment: Si esto es pseint, y no python, entonces deberia tener esa etiqueta...

Comment: Es el título más despistador de la historia del mundo mundial de StackOverflow :) No hay que usar Python en el título tampoco!

Comment: ¿En seudocódigo no es obligatorio indentar instrucciones dentro de bloques?

Answer (score 0):

PseInt no puede manejar ficheros, pero supongamos que puede.
Hay errores de sintaxis en el código que posteas.
Por ejemplo en PSeInt la palabra clave `len` no existe, es `longitud`

Además está mal planteado el bloque Para

Quedaría así:

```
Leer car;
fichero <- car;

Para i <- 0 en Caracter Hacer
Si i != " " Entonces
   fichero = fichero + i;
Sino
   fichero = fichero + ",";
   i <- i+1;
FinSi
FinPara
Escribir "fichero";
```

Answer (score -1):

Es una implementación sencilla, te recomiendo estudies un poco sobre el lenguaje, si no no podrás entenderlo a profundidad, te paso el [link donde puedes aprender python con ejemplos](https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/):

```
car =input("Introduce car: ")
fichero = ""
for i in car:
  if i != " ":
     fichero += i
  else:
     fichero += ", "
print(fichero)
```